# Highlighting the cell above if value of the cell is less than 0.05

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet where if the cell's value is less than 0.05, I want only 1 cell above that cell to be highlighted.

Example:
0.320   0.667   0.690   0.111
**0.003**   0.918   0.050   **0.033**

So, I want to highlight the cells **ABOVE** the cells with values 0.003 and 0.033 (the bold values).

Comment: What about `=A1<0.05`? Write this in CF custom rule.

Comment: And what if I want to highlight the cells above those?

Comment: Then try `=A$2<0.05` and apply to `A1:D1`.